# Using MPI4PY in FedoraScientific

Tags: fedora, openmpi, mpi4py

Recently, I downloaded and installed Fedora Scientific 20 as I was
impressed with the list of included software.  My interest in the software
is due to the inclusion of the MPI framework.  I was able to compile and
execute a simple C program using mpicc and mpiexec.  However, I need some
help using MPI4PY to call OpenMPI using Python code.

At the terminal prompt, if I try:

> $ /lib64/openmpi/bin/mpiexec -n 2 python3 helloworld.py

The Traceback reports that an

> ImportError: No module named 'mpi4py'

has been raised.  The helloworld.py program was an example found online with
line 6 being `from mpi4py import MPI`.

Since Apper indicates that mpi4py has been installed for both Python2 and
Python3 for OpenMPI as part of the installation of Fedora Scientific, I'm not sure what might be wrong.  Could somebody please advise as to how to use this package?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is something wrong with your environment.  Perhaps mpi4py, since you have confirmed it is installed, is installed in a  a strange place.  Would setting PYTHONPATH help?

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables